# display data from the MySQL database into an HTML

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I tried to display data from the MySQL database into an HTML table using PHP, everything works fine except for "Cars requested" it shows above the table not inside the table

[image]

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
    <!-- <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <title>tables</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    
    <tr>
    <th>Customer name</th>
    <th>Customer phone</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Cars requested</th>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root"; // For MYSQL the predifined username is root
    $password = ""; // For MYSQL the predifined password is " "(blank)
    $db = "car";
    
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db);
if ($conn->connect_error)  {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT fname, phone, age, test from info";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["fname"]. "</td> <td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td><td>" . $row["age"] . "</td></td>" .$row["test"] . "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

else
{
    echo "0 result";
}
$conn->close();
?>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Cars requested is a checkbox

Comment: "</td></td>"  before .$row["test"]  should be  "</td><td>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print code `echo` should look like this:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["fname"]. "</td> <td>" . $row["phone"] . "</td><td>" . 
$row["age"] . "</td><td>" .$row["test"] . "</td></tr>";
```

The table structure was not closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 "</td></td>" .$row["test"]
```

This is the issue I guess. It should be `<td></td>` and not `</td></td>`.